# How to change base branch of working branch in git?

Tags: git

I have a branch C created from B. B is created from A.

```
A_________________________
    B |____________________ 
           C|____________________
```

I need to change the base branch of C to A. Is there a way to do this in git?

I know the solution to create a new branch from A and to cherry-pick commits of C. But I want to know if there is a way to do this on the existing branch so that I need not close my existing PR rather I can force push the edited branch content.

Comment: Welcome to the wondrous world of [rebasing in Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). Note that it is a kind of [history rewriting](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), so <del>here there be dragons</del> <ins>there are some things to consider</ins>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `git rebase --onto` here:

```
# from branch C
git rebase --onto A C~1
```

In plain English, the above says to place the commit whose parent is `C~1` (which is just the `C` commit) onto a *new* base, `A`.

Note: Replace the `1` in `C~1` with the correct number of commits to reach the parent commit of the base of branch C.

Comment: It's IMO unclear from the question how many commits are on each of the involved branches.

Comment: For a lot of good insight on rebasing with --onto see this blog post: https://womanonrails.com/git-rebase-onto

Comment: @michid You know, I think you're **onto** something haha.

Comment: `git rebase --onto A B C` helped me